# Two problems in one? Failed to load lvmetad and you don't have enough free space

Tags: boot, 18.04, filesystem, lvm

so today I turned on my 18.04 machine for the first time in a month, clicked "okay" to the updater, and seconds later was given a message that said, "You don't have enough free space to install this." Weird, because I have a 1TB hard drive, and I have used maybe 150gb of it.  I did `apt autoremove`, and still had the error, so I started looking up my problem.  I tried to install `gparted`, but failed because there was not enough space.  I restarted my computer.  On reboot, I encountered a new error: "Failed to load lvmetad, begin device scanning."  This led to a halt in the boot process. I have looked each of these problems up, and they seem to be tightly interlaced.  To solve the `lvmetad` problem, it seems that I need to upgrade some files.  To solve the space problem, I need to install `gparted`.

I have followed more than a handful of guides on trying to fix both of these, but to no avail.  From these guides, I have come to realize that my boot partition is only ~487mb, and that seems to be the problem.  I have tried to figure out if it was possible to boot from the LVM, but I couldn't figure that out.  I believe that the root of the problem lies in the especially small boot partition.  Any help to get my machine back up and running is greatly appreciated.

Update: I have tried reinstalling using an ISO, but the boot from that also crashes.

Here's my df output:

[image]

Just as a note, it is saying that /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root is full, but before upgrading to 18.04, it was maybe 15% full.

Update:So now I ran `du | sort -n` (because the more complicated version wasn't working for me, and I got (I hope it's not still upside down):

[image]

This to me says that /var/log just dumped something in there.  Can I just `rm` everything in there?  I feel like that's too simple and too dangerous of an answer.

Update: I removed all `.gz` files, however no space was freed in `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root`.

Comment: `gparted` does not use any space on /boot, so you seem to be muddling you possible problems. Let's find out: Please edit your question to include the complete output of `df`.

Comment: sorry for the delay @user535733 I've only just gotten back to this problem.

Comment: Your boot partition seems be a healthy and normal 38%. It does not look like the problem to me. Next, show us [the biggest disk space hogs](https://superuser.com/questions/9847/linux-utility-for-finding-the-largest-files-directories) on your filesystem.

Comment: I've edited the post above to reflect the new output.  The logs are full, which to me says that it just continually wrote logs of something bad that was happening, and that this isn't the true problem.

Comment: How convenient: That's where I was leading you. Delete all the runaway log files except one to free space. Then read that one to learn the real problem. It really does not matter which one since it's probably the same problem over and over and over....

Comment: I think that it's a problem with postgresql. When booting, it would say `failed to connect to lvmetad` followed by something like `couldn't start postgresql 10`.

Comment: Ah, maybe not. When I do `du` inside of `/var/log`, the biggest things are `journal`, and `journal/[a long string that looks like a key]`. These two take 4,210,888 and 4,210,892 blocks respectively, yet the whole directory still claims to take up 119,319,888 blocks, which is absurd.